# Fail in percolating down a MIN binary heap under a specific case of children

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to implement a min-type of binary heap in my source cpp file, and testing it with some specific cases of different inputs and operations. However, my assertion test does not pass with the following sequence of operations:

```
    cout << "Testing percolate down  If there are two children nodes that are both smaller than 
    the parent... " << endl;
    heap.insert(23);
    heap.insert(43);
    heap.insert(234);
    heap.insert(321);
    heap.insert(243);
    cout<<"nerde"<<endl;
    cout << "Testing percolate down  If there are two children nodes that are both smaller than 
     the parent..." << endl;
    assert(heap.getMin() == 23);
    heap.deleteMin();
    assert(heap.getMin() == 43);
    heap.deleteMin();
    assert(heap.getMin() == 234);
    heap.deleteMin();
    cout<<"nerde78"<<endl;
    assert(heap.getMin() == 243);
    heap.deleteMin();
    assert(heap.getMin() == 321);
    heap.deleteMin();
```

my output gives an assertion fail at the above `cout<<"nerde78"<<endl;`

My heap array-based implementation starts with an index of 1 ( the zero index is not used). And I think that all of DeleteMin, GetMin, and Insert functions are correct. 
Heap's constructor:

```
  BinaryHeap::BinaryHeap(int capacity) {
    this->capacity = capacity;

    // The element at index 0 is not used!
    // The root element will be placed at index 1
    heap = new int[capacity+1];
    size = 0;

  }
```

Insert:

```
void BinaryHeap::insert(int element) {

    //Parcolate up
    if(size<capacity)
    {
        int hole=++size;
        for( ;hole>1 && element<heap[hole/2];hole/=2 )
        {
            heap[hole]=heap[hole/2];
        }
        heap[hole]=element;
    }
    // TO BE COMPLETED

    // The capacity of the heap is assumed to be fixed.
    // Insert the element if size < capacity
    // Do nothing otherwise.

    // After the new element is inserted, perform a percolate up operation here.
    // You can add a percolateUp method to the class,
    // or just implement the operations within this insert method.
}
```

DeleteMin:

```
void BinaryHeap::deleteMin() {


    if(size>=1)
    {
        heap[1]=heap[size-1];
        size--;
        percolateDown(1);
    }
}
```

GetMin:

```
int BinaryHeap::getMin() {
    if(size<1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
        return heap[1];

    // TO BE COMPLETED

    // If the size is less than 1, return -1
    // Otherwise, return the value of the root node


}
```

percolateDown:

```
void BinaryHeap::percolateDown(int hole) {

    // TO BE COMPLETED

    // Compare the node with its children; if they are in the correct order, stop
    // Otherwise, swap the element with the smallest child
    // Repeat the operation for the swapped child node
           int min_index = hole;
            int left = hole * 2  ;
            int right = hole * 2 + 1;
            if (left < size && heap[left]<heap[min_index]) {
                min_index = left;
            }
            if (right < size && heap[right]<heap[min_index]) {
                min_index = right;
            }

            if (min_index != hole) {
                swap(hole, min_index);
                percolateDown( hole);
            }
}
```

Swap:

```
void BinaryHeap::swap(int i, int j) {
    int t = heap[i];
    heap[i] = heap[j];
    heap[j] = t;
}
```

My current error message:

```
Assertion failed: heap.getMin() == 243
```

I am guessing that I need to include another if/else case for the percolate down combining both left and right child indexes to get passed from the mentioned case, but I did not really figure how. Maybe drawing the formed tree is a good idea.

Comment: "_I am guessing_" - why do you have to guess? Don't you have any other means to find out where the problem is?

Comment: This is a great time to use your debugger to see what's really going on.  In particular, since the problem seems to occur after deleting an element, you should check that `deleteMin` is doing what you expect to be doing.

Comment: The comparison `left < size` is appropriate for zero-based indexing.

Comment: @user3386109, you are right but I am changing the definition of left and right children accordingly.

Comment: When you insert an element, you need to make comparison not between element and parent, but between current node and parent in case of violation of the heap property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a bit insert method for more readability. First of all, we insert a new element to the end of an array if there is enough space. Then we check if the heap property is valid in other words we proceed up to the root swapping child and parent if the latter is greater.

```
void insert(int element) {

    if(size < capacity) {
        int hole = ++size;
        heap[hole] = element;

        while(hole > 1 && heap[hole] < heap[hole / 2]){
            swap(hole / 2, hole);
            hole /= 2;
        }

    }
}
```

Then in both functions deleteMin and percolateDown you have problems with indexing, because currently your algorithm implies zero-indexing. I've changed size - 1 to size.

```
void deleteMin() {
    if(size >= 1) {
        heap[1] = heap[size];
        size--;
        percolateDown(1);
    }
}
```

Similarly you need less or equal operator in percolateDown function for index comparison. Also, you proceed down from min_index not from hole which is a parent.

```
void percolateDown(int hole) {

    int min_index = hole;
    int left = hole * 2;
    int right = hole * 2 + 1;

    if (left <= size && heap[left] < heap[min_index]) {
        min_index = left;
    }
    if (right <= size && heap[right] < heap[min_index]) {
        min_index = right;
    }

    if (min_index != hole) {
        swap(hole, min_index);
        percolateDown(min_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! in particular, not-including the equality compression and incorrect recursive argument was the killer point! All tests are passed now.